# Static files in a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a rails app running and there is a JS based web app another wrote for us that is served from public/gui directory. Right now, I copy the gui/ files by hand. I am creating a Gem with the GUI files. I've seen railscast that requires
javascript from other assets,  but not when the html and JS are served from public/. How should this be done? Is there post-install script that can be automatically invoked from bundle install that can copy files from Gem directory to public/ in rails app? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Is this not doable? There are multiple HTML files in the Gem. I am still looking for a way to serve them up from public/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible follow below steps

1. Create a directory called app/assets/javascripts in the gem’s root directory put your js files in this folder
2. You just have to add **Engine** class in your gem assume your gem in **chart**

you just have to create a file named engine.rb in the lib/chart directory

```
module Chart
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

3.
You will have to require this **engine.rb** in your lib/chart.rb

```
require "chart/engine"
```

4.
Open app/assets/javascripts/application.js in your rails application and add below line

```
//= require chart
```

This will include all the assets under app/assets/ in the same way we include assets from our Rails app

Comment: Does this save the files, especially the HTML files in public/gui directory(folder)?